# Can IPSPs produce an action potential?

Tags: neuroscience

This picture was taken from Purves' Neuroscience, chapter 5:

[image]

Image (C) shows a inhibitory postsynaptic potential whose reversal potential "goes"  to the action potential. If two or more IPSPs occur, will temporal summation cause an action potential?

Comment: What do you think, based on the other information in C?

Comment: @BryanKrause I would say yes, but this seems to contradict the "inhibitory". Also, why is this "homework"?

Comment: This is exactly how I would write a homework or exam question for a basic neuroscience course. We don't allow answers to those sorts of questions, because the whole point is to work through it yourself. There are 2 other lines besides the IPSP voltage trace drawn in panel C. What do they mean? Also, have you looked at panel D? What is it telling you?

Comment: @BryanKrause Well, it isn't homework... It's a question I come up when reading Purves. I see that Panel D say say if the reversal potential is below the threshold the postsynaptic potential, and according to Purves, this is inhibitory because the change in V will be "pushed" toward the reversal potential of the specific synapse (GABA in this case). But if many inhibitory occur by definition, why can't the temporal summation of IPSPs be enough to reach the threshold value to fire the AP? this sum I'm thinking of can occur by different receptors.

Comment: What is the meaning of the reversal potential for a given ion or type of channel?

Comment: @BryanKrause The reversal potential is the equilibrium point given by Nerst's equation that separates two opposite directions of flux for the ion, this is to say that if a ion has a outward/inward flux, in the reversal potential the flux is zero, and past the reversal potential becomes inward/outward flux. Is this correct?

Comment: Yep. So what happens if you open a chloride channel when the cell is resting near the reversal potential for chloride?

Comment: @BryanKrause I think the voltage will be pushed towards the chloride reversal potential, because the flux of chloride will itself move towards its equilibrium potential.

Comment: So can IPSPs sum past their reversal potential?

Comment: @BryanKrause I feel the answer you expect is "no", but I'm not sure if I can give an argument for it. Would an explanation like this be valid? - If two channels X and Y are open, but with reversal potential lower than the threshold voltage, the SP are added as long as they are below the reversal potential (same direction of flux), and are subtracted if they are past the reversal potential (because the ion flux has changed direction). So the general answer is no.

Comment: Don't think of IPSPs/EPSPs summing necessarily. Opening conductances pushes the membrane potential towards whatever their reversal potential is (weighted against all the other open conductances). For excitatory conductances, summation is an okay approximation only because the difference between rest and threshold is small compared to the difference between rest and the reversal potential for typical excitatory receptors. I'll reopen and possibly write my own answer because I feel like you've done enough thinking now, but it would be best to edit your further thoughts into the Q.